# Getting Tally ERP data using javascript or angularjs to send it to server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, tally

I want to get data stored in tally and pass it to node server for manipulation. I am able to retrieve local tally data from local node server but I want to get remote tally data.  If I call same API from angular, I am not getting any response. In chrome I am getting  "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: to avoid the error of "net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" you need to use CORS to see the example
http://coimbatore-biz.com/blog/techsupport/Tally%20Request%20XMLsp0st889